# SCSS display horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, horizontal-scrolling

My code looks something like this:

```
    <div>
      <Button> // these buttons control horizontal scrolling
      <ScrollBar>
      <Button>
    </div>
```

My question is: how do I use SCSS to get them to display them horizontally rather than vertically stacked. Thank you!

Comment: Check out [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) as by assigning the display of the parent container to flex it default displays the child elements in a horizontal row.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <Button>
  <ScrollBar>
  <Button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `inline-flex` as well

Comment: That worked, thank you! What's the best way to add gaps between the buttons and the scroll bar?